# How to open random number of windows in python

Tags: python, tkinter

Why when pressing the "click for unknown" button a random number of windows aren't opening?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
import webbrowser
import random

random1 = random.randint(1,1000)
random2 = random.randint(1,1000)

#main window
master = Tk()

master.geometry("1920x1080")

label = Label(master, text ="This is the main window")
label.pack(side = TOP, pady = 10)

master.title("NotAVirus")

#second window
class NewWindow(Toplevel):

    def __init__(self, master = None):

        super().__init__(master = master)
        self.title("Lol Virus")
        self.geometry("500x200+",random1,"+",random2)
        label = Label(self, text ="This is a fake virus that might have worked we will find out :)")
        label.pack()
#button
btn = Button(master, text ="Click for unkown",)


btn.bind("<Button>",
    lambda e: NewWindow(master))


btn.pack(pady = 10)

mainloop()
```

Comment: try `master.mainloop()` also change `self.geometry("500x200+",random1,"+",random2)` -> `self.geometry(f"{random1}x{random2}")`

Comment: It's not clear why you think more than one window should pop up. You're only creating one new instance of `NewWindow`.

Comment: OK so @JacksonPro, so I changed to the above code and no real difference that I see, only 1 window opens.

Comment: @BryanOakley Well this is something I really don't understand. My son thinks I know everything when in reality I know nothing. How would I create multiple new instances when multiple should equal a random number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here You go, improved Your code a bit:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Button, Label, Toplevel
import random


random1 = random.randint(1, 1000)
random2 = random.randint(1, 1000)

#main window
master = Tk()

master.geometry("1920x1080")

label_main = Label(master, text="This is the main window")
label_main.pack(side='top', pady=10)

master.title("NotAVirus")


def create_windows():
    for i in range(random.randint(1, 1000)):
        NewWindow(master)


# second window
class NewWindow(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.title("Lol Virus")
        self.geometry(f"500x200+{random1}+{random2}")
        label = Label(self, text="This is a fake virus that might have worked we will find out :)")
        label.pack()
        self.update()


# button
btn = Button(master, text="Click for unkown", command=create_windows)

btn.pack(pady=10)

master.mainloop()
```

the explanation part. I assume You thought that `.geometry` sets the amount of windows or at least You wanted the windows to be scattered around randomly. two issues there. the random function gets called just once, so You will get just two random numbers which won't change.

next thing: to create multiple windows You need to actually create them, one of the ways is to just use a for loop, where we can actually insert the random bit and it will get the random number each time the function is called (also quick note, if a bigger random number is chosen it will take a while to create all of those windows.)

and lastly there is no need to really bind a button to a function, button classes have a parameter called `command=` which will execute the given func once the button is pressed.

now about those random bits:

```
class NewWindow(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        random1 = random.randint(1, 1000)
        random2 = random.randint(1, 1000)
        self.parent = parent
        self.title("Lol Virus")
        self.geometry(f"500x200+{random1}+{random2}")
        label = Label(self, text="This is a fake virus that might have worked we will find out :)")
        label.pack()
        self.update()
```

You can move them inside the class so that they get called each time a class instance is created

Comment: Thank you @Matiiss, this seems to work far better than before however the text "This is a fake virus that might have worked we will find out :)" seems to appear in the main window rather than the newly created windows

Comment: @AndyRoe: `label = Label(self.parent,...)` needs to be `label = Label(self, ...)`

Comment: @AndyRoe yep I found it, there was a 'typo', edited the code now, it was that I defined master as self.parent when in fact it should have been just self

Comment: @AndyRoe also if You noticed I added the random part for those windows so that they appear in random places too

Comment: Thank you @BryanOakley, My son will be impressed, I will read up on the above to better understand to try to help him better but also make him read it as well to understand :)

Comment: Thank you @Matiiss, I really appreciate your's and BryanOakleys help

Comment: @AndyRoe actually a quick note: I edited the code (very little) but basically I added `self.update()` function to the classes after packing, since otherwise it will create all the windows and only then put labels, this update funciton will ensure that window is created with the label (not the best wording of what it actually does but hope You understand, there is a huge visual difference with and without the func), also if You have questions, ask

Comment: Thank you @Matiiss, My son is happy and I will send him here to read your explanations above and to show I didn't fix it like he thinks :) I will have him sign up here too as I know how good a resource this can be

Comment: @Matiiss: generally speaking, calling `update()` is an antipattern. Perhaps a better solution would be to use `after` to schedule  the creation of each window after a short delay. See [Update considered harmful](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Update+considered+harmful) for a discussion of why calling `update` isn't recommended.

Comment: @BryanOakley ok, but I noticed that using `after` somehow affects all of the windows in that the script freezes for the `time in after * number of windows`

Comment: @Matiiss: `after` doesn't affect anything when you call it correctly. It simply allows the event loop (`mainloop`) to continue to process events before the `after` timeout has ended.

Comment: @BryanOakley ok, but even tho I added like 15ms to the after (was it necessary to add any other params?) in the NewWindow class it took like two seconds for those windows to even start appearing, so that is certainly somehow related

Comment: @Matiiss: after should always be called with at least two parameters: a delay in milliseconds and a command to run when that time period has passed.

Comment: @BryanOakley I guess I got what You are saying, there should be a function that 'updates' the screen (removes and packs a label or sth) and that funciton should be called with `after` recursively?